# how to configure data factory to connect to sql server behind NSG

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-nsg

I have a sql server running on a VM which and have configured NSG for the VM. I would like use azure data factory to connect to the database.

How do I set an NSG rule to allow data factory to connect to sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, It is not currently possible to identify the IP Address of the DF. You may also vote this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/20565967-identify-ip-address-of-data-factory). So one option is to whitelist the [Azure datacenter IP address](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653) list with filtering DF region.